# Unable to compile under Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I attempt to compile my Android project under AS 3.0 Canary 1 (it works fine on AS 2.3.2 stable version) but failed with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesUatGoogleDebug'.
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesUatGoogleDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:226)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:527)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(SplitScope.java:243)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:238)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:182)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:301)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.createSources(ZFile.java:1586)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1546)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1625)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeFile(ApkZFileCreator.java:141)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateFiles(IncrementalPackager.java:170)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateAssets(IncrementalPackager.java:229)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:525)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:359)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(SplitScope.java:187)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(SplitScope.java:204)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$null$8(SplitScope.java:226)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:237)
    ... 41 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.createSources(ZFile.java:1586)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1546)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1625)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1499)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension.updateManifest(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:241)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension.access$000(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:52)
        at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$0(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:168)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2099)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:871)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1161)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:172)
        at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:213)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:330)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:535)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:359)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(SplitScope.java:187)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(SplitScope.java:204)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$null$8(SplitScope.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:237)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:198)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:182)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:301)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor387.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:161)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:226)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:120)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:101)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:527)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


BUILD FAILED in 2s
18 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 12 avoided (67%)
```

I am not sure if that is related to the guava 19.0 library I imported. The libraries I used are listed below:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], excludes: ["pushservice-${baiduLibVersion}.jar", 'native-libs.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile "com.android.support:support-fragment:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:percent:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${playServiceLibVersion}"

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${playServiceLibVersion}"
    // Cloud Messaging and Notifications
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${playServiceLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${playServiceLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServiceLibVersion}"
    // google account login
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServiceLibVersion}"

    compile('com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:AutoFitTextView:3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile('com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile('com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'in.co.ophio:secure-preferences:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.githang:com-phillipcalvin-iconbutton:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.seanzor:shared-preferences-helper:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@jar'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.bigkoo:pickerview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.7.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.vdurmont:semver4j:2.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
    checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:6.5'
}
```

Comment: did you get it to run?

Comment: No, I can't get it run.

Comment: same here, I think it's guava and firebase versioning related issue here

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firebase team have suggested to use this as a fix :

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

EDIT:
Including the new updated package will auto-exclude the guava-jdk5 package.

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

Comment: Could you please post the source as well? Where did you get the answer from firebase team?

Comment: This seemed to be the issue! Thanks! I would also like to know where you get your information? Did you get in contact with the Firebase guys directly or could you provide a source? @mohamed-alouane

Comment: I just upgraded to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4 and saw this error. Oh my goodness, scratched my head for 2 hours til found this...Who on earth would know how to fix that by doing this...........

Comment: Source : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/271#issuecomment-304424918

Comment: The new version will automatically exclude the guava package:

`classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'`

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem, when I created a new project, and added the lines one by one.

The line that was causing the problem is

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'
```

that was in the project `build.gradle` file. Removing that line fixes the issue.

Comment: I cannot remove firebase library since I need it for crash reporting and analytics.

Comment: @David I only needed this for the new "Performance" features. You won't need this line for the crash reporting.

Comment: @macmoonshine this is the line that was causing the issue.

The quickest workaround was to comment it or remove it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see. I've edited your answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the new Android plugin version 3.0.0-alpha1

Just revert the plugin to 2.3 or 2.4-alpha7 and use gradle 3.5, it will work with the Firebase Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Other than `firebase` if you have any other build script (maybe custom build scripts), that is using `Guava` library you must upgrade it to `guava:21:0` or exclude guava from it

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the "Execution failed for task" error starting with Android studio 2.4 and now 3.0 canary running on my Win7 PC.  What seems to help for me is to run Task Manager and then kill the java.exe process.  The build runs through cleanly after that for me.