# org.gradle.tooling.BuildException in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading my AS to 3.0 Canary 3, I am unable to compile my app. Below is the stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:239)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:226)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:527)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(SplitScope.java:243)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:238)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:182)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:301)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.parallelForEachOutput(SplitScope.java:237)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.createSources(ZFile.java:1586)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1546)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1625)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeFile(ApkZFileCreator.java:141)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateFiles(IncrementalPackager.java:170)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateDex(IncrementalPackager.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:523)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:359)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(SplitScope.java:187)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(SplitScope.java:204)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$null$8(SplitScope.java:226)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.createSources(ZFile.java:1586)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1546)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1625)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1499)
            at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension.updateManifest(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:241)
            at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension.access$000(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:52)
            at com.android.apkzlib.sign.ManifestGenerationExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$0(ManifestGenerationExtension.java:168)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2099)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:871)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1161)
            at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:172)
            at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:213)
            at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:330)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:535)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:359)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(SplitScope.java:187)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(SplitScope.java:204)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.SplitScope.lambda$null$8(SplitScope.java:226)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104374/unable-to-compile-under-android-studio-3-0-canary-1/44121441#44121441) may help you.

To sum up, I had to remove `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0` that was causing this error.