# Unable to find method (can't compile project) after gradle update

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to update the gradle version in my project to 4.1-milestone-1 following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle)

My current gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Sat Jun 17 21:17:43 IDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

My current project build.gradle file buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

When trying to compile the project I get this error:

> Error:(1, 0) Unable to find method
>   'com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

- I tried cleaning the project
- I tried to click re-download dependencies and sync project, but I get
  the same error.
- I deleted my previous .gradle file in my home directory and in my
  project but I get the same error.
- I tried killing the java process and android studio but I get the
  same error.
- I tried killing all gradle's daemons but I get the same error

Comment: You've tried everything so may be 3rd reason is the problem `Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.`

Comment: How can I figure out which plugin it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had firebase in my buildscript dependencies, so it looked something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') //the firebase line
        ....
    }
}
```

I finally solved the issue by replacing the firebase classpath line with this:

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

So now my gradle build script looks something like this

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
        apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
        repositories {
            ...
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
            classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
                exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
            }
            ....
        }
    }
```

After that, all I had to do was clean the project, kill the gradle daemon

```
./gradlew --stop
```

And restart studio, and the issue was solved.

Comment: Can you explain why excluding **guava** worked ? I also have the Firebase plugin and after including your lines it built without any errors.

Comment: Source : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/271#issuecomment-304424918

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104374/unable-to-compile-under-android-studio-3-0-canary-1#comment76853207_44218754