# Cannot compile with Firebase Performance. (Unable to find method...)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-performance

I'm trying to add [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android) to my Android Studio project. After I followed the steps on how to add it to my app, I cannot compile my app. This is the error:

> Error:(1, 0) Unable to find method 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V'.
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   *Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)*
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   *Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)*
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**Project build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.0'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    // Version
    versionCode = 1;
    versionName = "0.0.1";

    ...

    // Firebase
    firebaseVersion = '11.0.2'

    ...
}
```

**App build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "REMOVED"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        dataBinding.enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = rootProject.ext.sourceCompatibility
        targetCompatibility = rootProject.ext.targetCompatibility
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    
    // Firebase
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebaseVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$rootProject.firebaseVersion"

    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try clean and rebuild project

Comment: @MartinDeSimone Just tried clean project, it gives the same error: `Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`

Comment: but without the library i mean

Comment: @MartinDeSimone That works, but like I said in my question, it gives an error when I add Firebase Performance to the project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44862981/6576875.

Comment: @MartinDeSimone Thanks, that worked! I did search on StackOverflow first, but didn't find that question because it isn't tagged with `firebase` or `firebase-performance`.

Comment: No problem, if you are ok with it i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably had firebase in your buildscript dependencies.

The problem was that I had firebase in my buildscript dependencies, so it looked something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') //the firebase line
        ....
    }
}
```

replacing the firebase classpath line with this:

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Then you have to clean the project, kill the gradle daemon and restart android studio.

[Unable to find method (can't compile project) after gradle update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44862981/6576875)

Comment: It is done, before i was on my mobile device so it wasnt easy